# mysql server is both running and not running

Tags: mysql

> There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
> Stop it yourself and try again!
> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
> new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.10.1_amd64.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

but when I try to stop it I get this

> sudo service mysql stop

> Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.

I can't install anything mysql related nor uninstall anything with apt.

Comment: When you check for running processes, is there a MySQL instance running under a user account?

Comment: no I can't see any mysql services running when i enter sudo ps -aux

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep mysql` please add this to your question. also `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but here's what fixed in my case:

- Check for any broken service link (`/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service` )
- Remove any MariaDB stuff (`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep maria`)
- Details found [here](https://blog.kesavan.info/2024/03/03/fix-for-mysql-8x-installation-failure-on-ubuntu-20-04/)